# One to many resource relationship returns empty

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to return a relationship using Laravels API resource classes. Each order has many order totals.

**My orders model**

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Orders extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'zen_orders';

    public function ordersTotals() {
        return $this->hasMany(OrdersTotalsModel::class, 'orders_id');
    }
}
```

**My orders resource**

```php
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class OrdersResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->orders_id,
            'customername' => $this->customers_name,
            'paymentmethod' => $this->payment_method,
            'datePurchased' => $this->date_purchased,
            'status' => $this->orders_status,
            'currency' => $this->currency,
            'orderTotal' => $this->order_total,
            'ordersTotals' => new OrdersTotalsResource($this->id),
        ];
    }
}
```

**My orders total model**

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OrdersTotalsModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'zen_orders_total';
    protected $primaryKey = 'orders_total_id';

    public function ordersTotals() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Orders::class, 'orders_id');
    }
}
```

**My orders total resource**

```php
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class OrdersTotalsResource extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'type' => $this->title,
            'amount' => $this->value,
          ];
    }
}
```

**I'm currently getting this error with the code provided:**

```php
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function toBase() on null in file
```

**Previous to this error I would just get this:**

```php
{
    "id": 389331,
    "customername": "John Smith",
    "paymentmethod": "Credit/Debit Card",
    "datePurchased": "2017-01-01 00:11:28",
    "status": 3,
    "currency": "GBP",
    "orderTotal": "36.99",
    "ordersTotals": []
},
```

I've followed the documentation as best I can and tried all the possible methods demonstrated there, I believe the orders total model isn't being called as any changes I make to the model and resource don't make a difference.

Comment: i think it should be `'ordersTotals' => new OrdersTotalsResource($this-> ordersTotals);`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it definitely did something, it's now giving me Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: it should be `$this->orders_total_id` instead `$this->id`  in `OrdersTotalsResource` toArray function

Comment: @rkj I've tried what you suggested, however now I'm getting: `BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::mapInto does not exist.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was wrong, for future visitors I was trying to retrieve records from a relationship using a resource.

On the **Orders Resource** I added:

```
'ordersTotals' => OrdersTotalsResource::collection(
OrdersTotalsModel::where('orders_id', '=' , $this->orders_id)
->orderBy('sort_order')
->get()
),
```

I was querying the model wrong, and had my primary keys mixed up.

I used this debug method to help diagnose where I was going wrong.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        if (env('APP_DEBUG') == true) {
            Event::listen('Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted', function ($query) {
                Log::debug($query->sql . ' - ' . serialize($query->bindings));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This would then log the query into the /storage/logs/laravel.log file